# How to replace font awesome icons with custom icons in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in my rails app, it displays a font awesome icon depending on wheteher the user selected the item.

My question is can I replace the font awesome icon with a custom icon from my assets/image file, if so I would appreciate if anyone could show me how to do this.

```
    <li class="<%= 'fa fa-times' if !@room.is_tv %>"> Cable TV</li>
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: What exactly do you mean in custom icon ?

Comment: I've dowloaded a set of icons from flat icon, and placed them in my assets/images folder, Im simply trying to replace the font awesome icon with those contained in my images folder but just getting sytax errors with attempting to code it Im still learning rails so just looking for some example code to get me going in the right direction

Comment: I'm pulling the icons in elsewhere fine using <img src="<%= asset_path( 'tool.png' ) %>" /> but haven't been able to incorporate that with line of code checking for the presence of the TV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a rails image_tag helper. As long as its within the images folder so the asset pipeline knows where to look you could use

```
<%= image_tag('name-of-img.png') %>
```

EDIT from comments:

```
<% if !@room.is_tv %>
  <li>
    <%= image_tag('sign.png') %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

From what you put in the comments

```
 <li><img src="<%= asset_path 'sign.png' if !@room.is_tv %>">TV</li>
                                                              ^This part is whats rendering text
```

Comment: I have it pulling the image in with this line now, I'm now trying not to show the TV text just the image when the TV is not present.                                                   <li><img src="<%=  asset_path 'sign.png' if !@room.is_tv %>">TV</li>

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help working as I wanted, really appreciate it!

Answer (score -2):

try to add new icons with

- 1- first method add this link in you projet